# problem in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00936

I have a query

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
  (No_COUNT)
VALUES 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM TABLE2)
```

On executing in am getting

```
ORA-00936: missing expression error.
```

Any idea why above query showing error?

Comment: You don't use keyword VALUES when values will be inserted by subquery. Syntax is INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,...) VALUES (val1,val2,val3,...) OR INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) SELECT * FROM ...

Answer (score 13):

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
(
    No_COUNT
)
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    TABLE2;
```